# qooxdoo destruct , dispose

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

Could any one please give a full example of how dispose and destruct are working in qooxdoo 1.6 ? , I can't find any good example in the qooxdoo demos or documentation.

thanks in advise .

Answer (score 3):

Disposal and destruction are in reality the two sides of the same coin: Disposal is the act of destructing objects. Their difference might become clearer to you by thinking of __destruct() as an onDispose() method.

As a rule of thumb, any class that creates QX objects is responsible for their proper destruction. Normally this is done the class' destructor, but may happen at any time depending on your business logic.

Disposal is done via the (ex.)

```
this._disposeObjects("_buttonOk", "_buttonCancel");
this._disposeArray("_children");
this._disposeMap("_registry");
```

calls. Some classes may provide explocit methods for their destruction, as in qx.ui.core.Widget

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to implement dispose if you work with object. Only destruct is needed, and not for everything (see above to catch which one you should delete, which one you don't need to)

It will looks like this :

```
qx.Class.define("q.view.Home"),{
    extend : qx.ui.core.Widget,
    construct:function(){
        this.base(arguments);
    },
    members:{
        __qooxdoo_object:null
    },
    destruct:function(){
        this._disposeObjects("__qooxdoo_object");
    }
});
```

As simple as this.
On the memory management link : this is extremely important : "qx.disposerDebugLevel" : "2"

It will automatically report (on firebug for example) object who are not properly destroyed.

So you will be able to know exactly what you should delete, what is deleted in a proper way.

Also, imagine this, you got a container (Composite for example, or anything) with 5 children and you want to empty the content but not the container, you should do like that :

(according container is the parent element of all children)

```
var childrenList = container.removeAll();
for(var i=0; i<childrenList.length; ++i){
  childrenList[i].dispose();
}
```

If you only dispose objet for some reason i don't know the Widget class (in qooxdoo framework) sometimes raise error. If you only removeAll, it will not dispose children but only remove them.
If you do both (dispose and removeAll), you will have no problem and children properly disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the document in the qooxdoo manual about memory management could be helpful:
http://manual.qooxdoo.org/devel/pages/development/memory_management.html

Comment: yes I have read this but there is not any example with a class that implements Dispose and Destruct... to see how it works